# Is there a name for this type of mathematical fallacy on inequality?

Tags: inequality

For concave $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I find that someone states:
\begin{align}
\max_{\substack {\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = X \\ \sum_{k=1}^n y_k= Y}} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_ky_k) \leq n f\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k/n\right),
\end{align}
hence the maximum argument of LHS must satisfy
\begin{align}
x_1y_1 = x_2y_2 =\ldots = x_n y_n.
\end{align}
However, the RHS may not satisfy the sum constraints.
Is there any name for this type of fallacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super hard to answer questions like this in the negative, but I suspect not. It's far too specific to be a named fallacy. Named fallacies tend to mostly be named by philosophers, and this is too specialised to be considered by a philosopher.

If you want to name it yourself, you can take your pick! Might I suggest the "Infeasible Symmetry Fallacy"?